# open react navigation app in a specific screen everytime

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, jsx, expo

On the following example app:

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/tree/master/example

if you do the following:

1. open the app
2. go to some specific screen
3. close the app
4. open the app

then, the app will be opened on the same screen it was just before closing it.

**What I want to do is** open the application in some specific screen everytime independently of the last visited screen.

On this link: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html

I found the following code which could be useful:

```
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 1,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Profile' }),
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Settings' }),
  ],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

but in case that it does the trick, my question is:

Where and how do I have to use that code?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure, but by closing, perhaps you are only minimizing the application?

Comment: think you need to mix [AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) with [Navigation Events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-events.html) and check `if Appstate=='background'` go to specific screen using `onWillFocus` Listener

Answer (score 2):

```
const ScreenStack = createStackNavigator({
  Screen1,
  Screen2,
  Screen3
},
{ initialRouteName: 'Screen1' })
```

You can define, initialRouteName for your first route..

But if you want to reset the router, create a NavigationService.
detail: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigating-without-navigation-prop.html